# How to add parameters to urls in Django?

Tags: python, django, view, field

I have a view that filters the field called "defaultfieldname" in a certain object_list. What I want to do is to adapt it to pass the name of the field as as parameter in urls.py, so I could use different urls for different fields.

I am not sure which way would be easier:

```
url(r'^calendar/birthday/$', login_required(MonthCalends.as_view(model=Person)), name='bday_list', filter_field="birthdate"),
url(r'^calendar/deathday/$', login_required(MonthCalends.as_view(model=Person)), name='dday_list', filter_field="deathdate"),
```

or

```
url(r'^calendar/birthday/$', login_required(MonthCalends.as_view(model=Person, filter_field="birthdate")), name='bday_list'),
url(r'^calendar/deathday/$', login_required(MonthCalends.as_view(model=Person, filter_field="deathdate")), name='dday_list'),
```

Then I have a view:

```
class MonthCalends(ListView):
    template_name='month_list.html'
    ## Sets default fieldname value
    filter_field = "defaultfieldname"
    ...rest of code
```

The param in urls.py should overwrite the "defaultfieldname" on the view, but I don't know how to get the filter_field from the urls.py in the view. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you planning to use the `filter_field` value? For example: are you going print it on the page or get the `Person.birthdate` field and print that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments you send with `as_view` are set on the MonthCalends object. That means `filter_field` is available as `self.filter_field`. Assuming you have defined the `get` method you could do as follows:

```
class MonthCalends(ListView):
    template_name='month_list.html'
    ## Sets default fieldname value
    filter_field = "defaultfieldname"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # if the filter field was sent as an argument
            filter_field = self.filter_field
        except:
            # else revert to default
            filter_field = MonthCalends.filter_field
        # ...rest of code
```

For a more full explanation check the [Django class based views documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#view).

Comment: This get() function is giving the error:

The view calend.views.MonthCalends didn't return an HttpResponse object.

I think its missing the return line..

Comment: This code assumes you have the rest of the `get` function, so that's why it's missing the return. 

`return super(ListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Perfect! I just changed to `return super(MonthCalends, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)` Working fine as specified, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may just use one url, that triggers the second part of your url:

```
url(r'^calendar/(\w+)$', login_required(MonthCalends.as_view(model=Person)), name='bday_list'),
```

Then you may access it using `self.args[0]`

And in case you just permit two different types for `filter_field`, you may just raise an exception later in the class that you have read `self.args[0]`.

Of course, you may use more readable syntax in the regex like:

```
r'^calendar/(?P<type>\w+)$'
```

In this case you can access it using `self.kwargs['type']`.

Anyway, using regex groups seems much neater.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kamyar, but that's not what I want. The url part is different from the field_names. Like the url r'^calendar/birthday/ uses birthDATE field. There are other fields with totally different names so regex groups doesn't solve my problem.